# Bootstrap. Make some container elements "fixed"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I have this bootstrap container, (actually bootstrap-vue).

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMGoGL#anon-login

I'm trying to make my "TOPBAR" and my "SEARCHBOX" fixed, so that only the paragraph section with the Lorem Ipsum text has a scroll. The rest must be fixed  (always visible) at the top of the page.

The problem I have with `position:fixed` is that the paragraph goes on top of the "TOPBAR"

Is it possible to achieve what I'm looking for?

*UPDATE*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the topbar and searchbox in the same row with `position:fixed` and `top: 0` to fix it at the top, and put the paragraph in its own row. You can use the [`z-index` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index) to make sure the content scrolls "under" the top-bar, not over.

You can use:

```
  width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
```

to make sure `fixed-bar` has the same width as the container.

Demo: https://codepen.io/glhr/pen/BEQjzj

Comment: Sorry this is not what I'm aiming for. The topbar should be on top in the first row. In the second row, I need searchbox and paragraph. But when paragraph grows and the users scrolls down, the searchbox must be visible. In your example paragraph is aligned with the topbar: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJNYMK

Comment: Almost there.when we enable the ```fixed-bar``` css, the width of the components is lost: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMGoGL

Comment: Updated my answer & demo.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more problem with this solution. You cannot interact with the top of paragraph. Try to select the text on the first line of the paragraph where it says "Lorem Ipsum". What this means in my screenshot is I cannot interact with the "Venta" green box on top

Comment: Good point, that's because of the z-index of `.fixed-bar`. Fix this by changing the height of `.fixed-bar` to something arbitrarily small. See updated demo: https://codepen.io/glhr/pen/BEQjzj

Comment: Rockstar! Thanks